# Jquery, getting .text() from div in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have code which works for every browser except IE (surprise, surprise).

This is tricky stuff though. We had a coldfusion custom tag which generates advertisement code in the body of the document. But, for page load speed reasons, we decided to try and load the code returned from the custom tag using jQuery after the document was ready.

We've tried nearly every possible method, each with its own hassles. Finally settled on calling the custom tag in a hidden div at the bottom of the page initially, then using jQuery to get the specific portion of the code we needed and loading it into its final resting place further up the page.

We have five ads altogether. One of them returns code that IE can't work with. The rest all work fine.

The four OK ads return a hyperlink string from the custom tag (e.g. as follows), which is easy to work with and works in all browsers:

```
<a href="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=brd&amp;FlightID=2997227&amp;Page=&amp;PluID=0&amp;Pos=9088" 
   target="_blank">
    <img src="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=bsr&amp;FlightID=2997227&amp;Page=&amp;PluID=0&amp;Pos=9088" 
         border="0" 
         width="300" 
         height="250">
</a>
```

We use the following code to load into temp div (divx), then extract and reload into final position (left2):

```
$('#divx').html("").load('/remoteAd.cfm?type=left2&referrer=/index.cfm', 
    function(g){
        var xx = $('#divx').html());
        $('#left2').html(xx);
});
```

HOWEVER, the troublesome one returned a huge block of code that broke javascript when we tried to assign it to a variable (I can't even load it here without it breaking. You can view it in the source code of [this page](http://www.allblacks.com/testAd.cfm)), so we decided to extract it using .text():

```
var xx = $('#divx').text();
```

instead of

```
var xx = $('#divx').html();
```

This extracts the following js STRING (complete with line breaks) in ALL BROWSERS EXCEPT IE:

```
ajaxinclude("/remoteAd.cfm?type=right1&referrer=/index.cfm");

function ebStdBanner1_DoFSCommand(command,args){
   try{
        command = command.replace(/FSCommand:/ig,"");
        if((command.toLowerCase() == "ebinteraction") ||   
           (command.toLowerCase()=="ebclickthrough")) 
            gEbStdBanners[1].handleInteraction(args);
        else if(command.toLowerCase()=="ebversiontrackingimpression")
            gEbStdBanners[1].ebversiontrackingimpression(args);
   } catch(e) {}
} 
function ebIsFlashExtInterfaceExist(){
    return true;
}

<a href="http://bs.sys.com/adServer.bs?cn=brd&FlightID=2997227&Page=&PluID=0&Pos=9088" 
   target="_blank">
    <img src="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=bsr&FlightID=2997227&Page=&PluID=0&Pos=9088" 
         border=0 
         width=300 
         height=250>
</a>
```

It's a simple matter to extract the hyperlink block from the string, thanks to suggestions from others on stackoverflow.

HOWEVER, in IE9, I get a blank result for `alert($('#divx').text());`
Can anyone tell me WHY?. It's ruining my day.

You can view the code that loads into the temp div by viewing the source code of [this page](http://www.allblacks.com/testAd.cfm). All I want to do is access this as text() and isolate the `<a>...</a>` block from it before loading that into its final div.

Comment: either its a typo here but this will cause a syntax error; `var xx = $('#divx').text());` should be `var xx = $('#divx').text();`

Comment: Please format your code, the easier you make it for others, the more they're inclinded to help.

Comment: @ibu - It's a typo - corrected it. The actual code doesn't have that.

Comment: @RobG - It's formatted as best as possible. Some of the strings are long. I'd rather leave them as long strings so people don't think I'm adding line breaks which would stuff javascript.

Comment: @user460114 I formatted the code for you, thought this might help you get the idea.

Comment: What browser/document mode are you in? I think I get correct data in Browser Mode: IE9 and Document Mode: IE9 standards. Switching document mode to anything other than IE9 standards returns empty .text() data.

Comment: @Josh Not sure how it's changed, but thanks.

Comment: @Denny Ferrassoli. IE9 Browser mode, but it was in Quirks document mode for some reason. I'm afraid I don't know much about modes, but doesn't it automatically go into quirks mode when there is an issue?

Comment: My doctype on this page is <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

Comment: Changing it to IE9 document mode DID fix the issue by the way, but I just need to know how it got into quirks mode. People shouldn't need to change their modes just to view the ad.

Comment: @user460114 I guess it's still awaiting peer review :)

Comment: It's sickening to think I've wasted two days fixing something just for IE.

Comment: Here's additional info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/19/testing-sites-with-browser-mode-vs-doc-mode.aspx and to force IE9 into standards mode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Denny Ferrassoli. Thank you! Forcing IE9 mode was the answer. Make your comment into an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What browser/document mode are you in? I think I get correct data in Browser Mode: IE9 and Document Mode: IE9 standards. Switching document mode to anything other than IE9 standards returns empty .text() data.

Including the additional information regarding this for future visitors:

Here's additional info:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/19/testing-sites-with-browser-mode-vs-doc-mode.aspx

and to force IE9 into standards mode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Bit difficult to say, but if i have to guess : You have duplicate ID's on your page.

IE can't process duplicate ID's [#divx] and will fail [not standard to have duplicates] , other browsers will manage to do this correctly... try switching all #divx to a class [.divx]. and try `$('.divx').text()`

Comment: Thanks for trying Marc, but it wasn't the solution.